# Почему Django не видит вторую таблицу бд?

Tags: python, django, таблицы

Я пытаюсь сделать бд для сайта на Django, для этого я сделал 2 таблицы, провёл миграции и записал всё в нужные файлы, в админ-панели появились новые таблицы, как и должно быть, в переменных chaps и subsections есть данные(проверил, они попадают в переменную), их я возвращаю, а потом данные из subsections теряются и html шаблон ничего не выводит, хотя chaps работает исправно, может быть это происходит из-за добавления в коллекцию двух элементов, а Django рассчитывает на один, но как это исправить, я не понимаю.
Я добавил ForeignKey, но он ничего не дал, т.к. мне нужен chap_name в шаблоне, а не просто знать, какой подраздел к какому разделу относится

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Chapter(models.Model):
    chap_name = models.CharField('Название раздела', max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.chap_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Раздел'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Разделы'


class Subsection(models.Model):
    root_chap_name = models.CharField('Раздел, в котором находится', max_length=50, default='')
    subsec_name = models.CharField('Название подраздела', max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField('Статья')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subsec_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Подраздел'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Подразделы'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Chapter, Subsection

chaps = Chapter.objects.all()
subsections = Subsection.objects.all()


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'chaps': chaps, 'subsections': subsections})


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'main/about.html', {'chaps': chaps, 'subsections': subsections})
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Chapter, Subsection

admin.site.register(Chapter)
admin.site.register(Subsection)
```

index.html

```
                  {% for el in chaps %}
                    <input type="checkbox" id={{ el.chap_name }} name="" value="">
                    <label for={{ el.chap_name }} class={{ el.chap_name }}1 id="header1">{{ el.chap_name }}</label>
                    <ul id="header1_list" сlass="">{{ subsection }}
                      {% for i in subsection %}
                        <li><a href="">{{ i.subsec_name }}</a></li>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                  {% endfor %}
```

[image: Таблицы бд]
[image: Вывод локального сервера]

Answer (score 0):

Естественно не работает.Ведь тебе для реализации разделов и подразделов можно просто реализовать Один ко многим через models.ForeignKey.И тогда ты сможешь при помощи методов их выводить в одном цикле for.Смотри -> https://metanit.com/python/django/5.6.php

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне нужен в html файле также и список всех разделов, а через ForeignKey я получаю только информацию о том, в каком разделе, какой подраздел находится, поэтому мне нужны данные из обоих таблиц